# Node.js Express - Get request path with query params

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I have a service that exposes these two endpoints

```
app.get('/test/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world');
});
```

I have a middleware that logs all request to these endpoints.
If the second endpoint is hit, I want to log `/test/:id` and not `/test/actualId`.

How can I extract the route from the `req` object in this way?

Comment: You should be able to access the route with: `req.route.path` [docs](https://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#req.route), but i am not sure if this works in middlewares.

Comment: Confirm, `req.route.path` works in middlewares. At least in express 4.*

Comment: So, @RolandStarke I guess you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @RolandStarke this works only after the endpoint has been hit. How can I get this value in a middleware that is called prior to the endpoint?

Comment: I fear you can't. But i guess you could register an event listener or monkey patch some method, to read `req.route.path` after its populated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `request.route.path` which will output the path string you provided:

```
app.get('/test/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.route.path)
    // -> /test/
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.route.path)
    // -> /test/:id
    res.send('hello world');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
app.get('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
   let actualId = req.query.id;
   let reqPath = req.originalUrl || req.path 
   res.send('hello world :', actualId);
});
```